# Redirect domains single pages and maintain url

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects

I have several domain names that need to point to individual pages on a single host and still maintain the URL.  For example:

`examplesite1.com` needs to point at `mainsite.com/examplesite1.php` but still display `examplesite1.com`

`examplesite2.com` needs to point at `mainsite.com/examplesite2.php` but still display `examplesite2.com`

The host doesn't allow parked domains and has very limited add-on domains, so it seems my only  way of linking the domains is via web forwarding.  I can get the forwarding to arrive at the correct pages, but I don't seem to have any control over it with `.htaccess` and therefore the actual URL displays - presumably because the redirect happens prior to arriving at the host.

Is there any way around this?  I'd rather not use the registrar's cloaking or use frames if I can avoid it.

**Edit: Requested info**

I have tried to implement this, examplesite1.com is set to forward to mainsite.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?examplesite1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainsite.com/examplesite1.php [R=301,L]
```

I've also tried several variations of similar `.htaccess` rules but nothing has any effect at all.

I have tried doing this with the 1 add-on domain that I'm allowed, adding examplesite1.com as an add-on domain.  This results in the correct page loading, but it displays the 'actual' url

Comment: Can you post the .htaccess code that you have tried, and what the results were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL changes then it's a redirect if doesn't then its not a redirect... there's no workaround. You don't want a redirect method as it won't work.

Theses are just some methods that will work:

- [iframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iframe#Frames)
- [domain masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Masking)
- [cross-site ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391249/how-to-perform-cross-site-ajax-request)
- [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)
- [ftpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPFS)
- shared hosting ([php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php))
- Remote SQL Sharing ..... list goes on....

I'm not going to explain every method since you can find all this info on stack overflow.

**Shared Hosting**

This is the easiest method.

Lets say you have:

- Mainsite = `var/www/`

  - SiteA = `var/www/siteA`
  - SiteB = `var/www/siteB`

    1. Make a *index.php* file in SiteA with `<?php include 'var/www/examplesite1.php';`
    2. Make another file in SiteB with `<?php include 'var/www/examplesite2.php';`